# Change of coordinates for partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm struggling with a solution to:

$ \frac{∂u}{∂x} + 3(\frac{∂u}{∂y}) + 10u = 20e^{10x}$.

I've been told to use the change of coordinates method, of the form $ξ = ax + by, η = bx - ay$ for a suitable choice of $a$ and $b$. I'm not sure what to do with the $20e^{10x}$ component. I'm not also sure on what the "for a suitable choice of $a$ and $b$" part means.

Comment: Shouldn't your second derivative be $\partial u/\partial y$?

Comment: You have to choose $a$ and $b$ in such a way that only one derivative remains (either with respect to $\xi$ or with respect to $\eta$. You use the chain rule to express your derivatives in terms of $\partial w/\partial\xi$ and $\partial w/\partial\eta$, where $w(\xi,\eta)=u(x,y)$ and choose $a$ and $b$. Once your equation only has one derivative, you integrate it easily. You should express $20e^{10x}$ as a function of $\xi$ and $\eta$ using the values of $a$ and $b$ you found.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ru_x+su_y+tu=v$ a PDE with real functions $r,s,t$ and $v$. Note the following: If you have such a linear first-order-PDE, in general a variable transformation will help to gain the solutions, whenever $\xi$ is a solution of the PDE $ru_x+su_y=0$. So we first need $\xi$.

Note further the following: Concerning the upper PDE, we call

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{s}{r}$$
the characteristic equation of the PDE. In the theory of the method of characteristics, you can do the following (with our example here, we have $\frac{s}{r}=3$): Write $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{3}=\mathrm{d}x,$ then integration yields $x+C=\frac{1}{3}y$ with a real number $C$. Equivalently, one gets $C=\frac{1}{3}y-x$ and you can choose

$$\xi:=C=\frac{1}{3}y-x$$

because this is an invariant of the characteristic equation. From your definitions, we immediately have

$$(a,b)=(-1,\frac{1}{3})$$

and so we get

$$\eta=\frac{1}{3}x+y.$$

So we now put our unknown function $u(x,y)$ as a new function $U$, i.e. $u(x,y)=U(\xi, \eta)$ and in more detail, it is $U=U(\xi(x,y), \eta(x,y))$. We plug this into the PDE using the multivariable chain rule:

\begin{align}u_x+3u_y+10u&=(U_\xi \xi_x+U_\eta \eta_x)+3(U_\xi \xi_y + U_\eta \eta_y)+10U\\
&=-U_\xi + \frac{1}{3}U_\eta + 3(\frac{1}{3}U_\xi + U_\eta)+10U \\
&=\frac{10}{3}U_\eta +10U \\
&=20\mathrm{e}^{10x}.
\end{align}

We still have to express $x$ in terms of $\xi$ and $\eta$. From the definition of $\xi$ and $\eta$ one immediately becomes $3\xi-\eta=-\frac{10}{3}x$, that means $x=-\frac{3}{10}(3\xi-\eta)$. This leads to

$$\frac{10}{3}U_\eta+U=20\mathrm{e}^{10(-\frac{3}{10}(3\xi-\eta))}=20\mathrm{e}^{-9 \xi}\mathrm{e}^{3\eta}.$$

As you can see, this is an ODE with respect to $\eta$. The ODE is linear, so we can use the structur theorem for lineary ODE to solve it: The general solution is the sum of the homogenous ODE and a particular solution of the inhomogenous ODE. Looking at the homogenous ODE $\frac{10}{3}U_\eta+10U=0$ one gets quick

$$U_{\text{hom}}=f(\xi)\mathrm{e}^{-3\eta},$$

where $f$ denotes a differentiable, real-valued function. Based on the right hand side, for the particular solution we use the approach $U_\mathrm{p}=A\mathrm{e}^{3\eta}$, whereby $A \in \mathbb{R}$. Plugging this into the inhomogeneous ODE gives us

$$\frac{10}{3}3A\mathrm{e}^{3\eta}+10A\mathrm{e}^{3\eta}=20\mathrm{e}^{-9\xi}\mathrm{e}^{3\eta},$$
so $A=\mathrm{e}^{-9\xi}$ and we have

$$U_\mathrm{p}=\mathrm{e}^{-9\xi}\mathrm{e}^{3\eta}$$
as a particular solution. For the general solution we obtain

$$U=U_\mathrm{hom}+U_\mathrm{p}=f(\xi)\mathrm{e}^{-3\eta}+\mathrm{e}^{-9\xi}\mathrm{e}^{3\eta}.$$

Transforming it back into the original variables we get the general solution of your PDE:

$$u(x,y)=f(-x+\frac{1}{3}y)\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-x-3y}+\mathrm{e}^{10x},$$

whereby $f$ is a differentiable function. For the sake of completeness, we check this now. We calculate the partial derivatives step by step:

$$u_x=\partial_x \left(f(-x+\frac{1}{3}y)\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-x-3y}+\mathrm{e}^{10x}\right)=-f'\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-x-3y} + f\cdot (- \mathrm{e}^{-x-3y})+10 \mathrm{e}^{10x}, $$

and with respect to $y$ we have

$$u_y=\partial_y \left(f(-x+\frac{1}{3}y)\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-x-3y}+\mathrm{e}^{10x}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot f'\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-x-3y}+ f \cdot (-3\mathrm{e}^{-x-3y}).$$

Now we put this together into the PDE:

\begin{align}u_x+3u_y+10u&=-f'\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-3x-3y}+f\cdot (-\mathrm{e}^{-3x-3y})+10\mathrm{e}^{10x}
+3(f'\cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-x-3y}+f\cdot(-3)\mathrm{e}^{-x-3y})\\
&+10(f\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-3x-3y} + \mathrm{e}^{10x})\\
&=20\mathrm{e}^{10x}.
\end{align}

Comment: I don't agree with your result $u(x,y)=f(-x+\frac{1}{3}y)\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-x-3y}+\mathrm{e}^{10x}$ . I think it should be : $$u(x,y)=f(-x+\frac{1}{3}y)\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-10x}+\mathrm{e}^{10x},$$ Also, I don't agree with your final checking.

Comment: @JJacquelin Can you explain where the problems are?

Comment: When I put your result into the PDE in order to repeat the checking as you did, I cannot find the same result as yours. It should be of interest that you edit your calculus step by step so that everybody could check each step. Of course you can ignore my remark if you are definitively sure of your result (which is not exactly the same as the result given in my answer). Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: @JJacquelin Ok, I will edit it later and tell you then. I think the main problem which I have with your answer is that your $\xi$ and $\eta$ don't match the definition OP wants (see the $a$ and $b$)?

Comment: OK. You are right I didn't follow the change of variables suggested in the wording of the question. For me, it seems better to start with a more general $ξ = ax + by, η = a'x +b'y$. After calculus and simplification, the simplest choice appears  $a=1,b=0,a'=1, b'=-1/3$.

Comment: Alternatively, I solve the problem thanks to the method of characteristics. I got the same result : $$u(x,y)=e^{10x}+e^{-10x}f(x-\frac13 y)$$

Comment: @JJacquelin so I made the test at the end a little bit more detailed but I don't know how to explain it more. I saw in the calculation that my solution works and I tested yours and it works too. Were is the mistake? Can the solutions be equivalent?

Comment: I agree with your test. Then, if we compare $$u=f_1(-x+\frac13 y)e^{-x-3y}+10e^{10x}$$ and $$u=f_2(-x+\frac13 y)e^{-10x}+10e^{10x}$$ we found the relationship $$f_1(X)=f_2(X)e^{9X}$$ This proves that your solution and mine are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{∂u}{∂x} + 3(\frac{∂u}{∂y}) + 10u = 20e^{10x}$$

$u(x,y)=v(\xi,\eta)\quad$ with the change of variables $\quad\begin{cases} ξ = x \\ η = x - \frac13 y \end{cases}$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= -\frac13 \frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta}$$

$$ \frac{∂u}{∂x} + 3(\frac{∂u}{∂y}) + 10u =\frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta}+3(-\frac13 \frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta})+10v= 20e^{10\xi}$$
$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi}+10v= 20e^{10\xi}$$
There is no $\eta$ in the equation which then is reduced to an ODE, linear, first order. Solving it leads to :

$v=e^{10\xi}+Ce^{-10\xi}$

where $C$ is a constant with respect to $\xi$, but of course not with respect to $\eta$.
$$v(\xi,\eta)=e^{10\xi}+e^{-10\xi}f(\eta)$$
Back to $(x,y)$ :
$$u(x,y)=e^{10x}+e^{-10x}f(x-\frac13 y)$$

Answer (score 0):

Equation is linear. Then solution is
$$u=u_h+u_p$$

$u_p=e^{10x}$ is particular solution.

$u_h$ is solution of homogenous equation $$u_x+3u_y+10u=0.\qquad(1)$$
Solution of $(1)$ we search in form
$$u=ve^{-10x}$$
For $v$ we get equation
$$v_x+3v_y=0.$$
It solution is
$$v=f(y-3x)$$
You can easily check this. Then general solution is
$$u=f(y-3x)e^{-10x}+e^{10x}$$